# typing module vs python object

Tags: python, type-hinting

I saw a lot of codes that use `Type hints`

and some of them use **python built-in object** as their type annotations and some of them use **typing module** for their type annotations

But what is the differences between `python objects` and `typing module`

It's better to say when to use *python object* as **type hints** and when to use *typing module* as **type hints**

for example what is the differences between bellow codes?

```
# first code
def message_users(users: list[str], msg: str) -> None:
    for user in users:
        print(f'User: {user} -> {msg}')

# second code
from typing import List
def message_users(users: List[str], msg: str) -> None:
    for user in users:
        print(f'User: {user} -> {msg}')
```

And other types like *typing.NamedTuple* or *collections.namedtuple*?
Which is better to use?

Comment: Did you [check the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List)? Was there any relevant information there?

Answer (score 2):

Beginning with python 3.9 you can use more standard types for type hinting.

See https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) states, `typing.List` was deprecated in python-3.9 and you can now use the 'normal' `list`.